# Removing a particular line in Text

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a small program with Tkinter and user asked me to add a function in which user could able to delete a particular line.

My question is how to delete a particular line of text in Tkinter?

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)

        self.parent = parent

        self.parent.state('zoomed')

        self.Scrol = tk.Scrollbar(self.parent)
        self.Text = tk.Text(self.parent, height=50, width=100)

        self.Scrol.pack(side="right")
        self.Text.pack()

        self.Scrol.config(command=self.Text.yview)
        self.Text.config(yscrollcommand=self.Scrol.set)

        self.Text.tag_configure('red', foreground='red', underline=1)

        self.count = 0
        self.Text.insert('end', "{} test test test".format(str(self.count)) + "\n", 'red')

        self.B = tk.Button(self.parent, text="add text", command=self.addText)
        self.B.pack()

        self.Text.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.deleteLine)

    def deleteLine(self, event):
        self.Text.delete(1.0, 2.0)

    def addText(self):
        self.count += 1
        self.Text.insert('end', "{} test test test".format(str(self.count)) + "\n", 'red')


root = tk.Tk()
app = MainApplication(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Now my code only deletes the first line every time when I click on any line. I would like to delete that line which I click on.

Comment: For future researchers, `self.Text.delete(1.0, 2.0)` _does_ remove the first particular line. Similarly `self.Text.delete(2.0, 3.0)` or `self.Text.delete('2.0', '3.0')` would remove the 2nd line in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deleting the current line the simplest way would probably be, as suggested in [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)['s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48590091/removing-particular-line-tkinter-python/48590954?noredirect=1#comment84181180_48590954), using `'current'` argument in `delete` directly:

```
def deleteLine(self, event):
    self.Text.delete('current linestart', 'current lineend+1c')
    #return "break" # uncomment if you want to disable selection caused by double-clicking
```

Comment: FWIW, you don't have to first convert the index. You can use `"current linestart"`

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I think this makes it a much simpler answer.

Comment: See earlier revision of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48590954/4), which had two somewhat more complicated solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the event.x and event.y attributes to get the line number the user clicked on and then use the Text widget to query what row that corresponds to. Finally delete the row. One side effect is that the text widget will select some text, because that is the default binding for the text widget when the double-button is clicked (not changeable unfortunately). You can remove the effects of that by returning "break" at the end of the deleteLine method.

```
def deleteLine(self, event):
    point = '@' + str(event.x) + ',' + str(event.y)
    line_number = self.Text.index(point).split('.')[0]
    self.Text.delete(line_number + '.0', line_number + '.end + 1 char')
    # Interrupt the default sel tag binding.
    return "break"
```

Comment: You _can_ disable selection caused by double-clicking manipulating `bindtag`s.

Comment: True. But since *the tag bindings will be invoked first, followed by bindings for the window as a whole* (from the Tk docs), changing the tag binding will have no affect in this case unfortunately.

Comment: Try replacing the last line in `deleteLine`  with `return "break"`.

Comment: Sweet :) I'll edit the answer with this more efficient solution. Thanks.